# Reading uint8_t from binary file

Tags: c++, file, binary

I have a file where are binary numbers and I have to read them. I use:

```
ifstream data("date.txt", ios_base::binary);

int count_16 = 0; //count how many uint16_s I have already read
uint16_t numbers_16; // Allocate storage for uint16_s
int count_8 = 0;
uint8_t numbers_8;
int count_char = 0;
char name[20];

data.seekg(0U, ios_base::beg); // Move the input position indicator to the beginning of the file for reading
data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&numbers_16), sizeof(uint16_t)); // into numbers_16
cout << numbers_16; 
count_16++;

data.seekg(count_16 * sizeof(uint16_t) + count_8 * sizeof(uint8_t) + count_char * sizeof(name+1));
data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&numbers_16), sizeof(numbers_16)); // Read the element into number
cout << numbers_16 << endl;
count_16++;
```

everything works untill that:

```
data.seekg(count_16 * sizeof(uint16_t) + count_8 * sizeof(uint8_t) + count_char * sizeof(name+1));
data.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&numbers_8), sizeof(numbers_8)); // Read the element into number
cout << numbers_8 << endl;
count_8++;
```

And here I don't get any number or anything readable.
I don't know why this method works for uint16_t but not for uint8_t. Can someone explain why it is wrong and how to read uint8_t from file?

Comment: can you post your data.txt file

Comment: Are the numbers in raw format or text?  Usually a ".txt" extension means ASCII text, i.e. 0x31 for '1' not 0x01.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to seek to the beginning of a file after opening it (unless you open it in append mode); the file is automatically set to the beginning.

Comment: According to your code, `count_8` is zero, thus the expression `count_8 * sizeof(uint8_t)` is also zero.  I understand why you are repositioning the file pointer.  Your program may be more efficient by reading in a structure or a block of data, rather than seeking to the next `uint16_t`.

Comment: BTW, the `count_char` is also zero.  Thus you are only seeking to `count_16 * sizeof(uint16_t)`.  Use a debugger.

Comment: Please post the *format* or *layout* of your input file.

Comment: well, I cannot send you input file, I wrote 'date.txt' as an example, the file has an extension made by my college and for sure there are only binary numbers. And this is only a part of long code, where I use some loops and that's why I need write count_char. And in the file there are various variables so I guess I can't just read a block of data because of it. Well my question is how read uint_8 from binary file?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it is good why of reading. The only mistake was here:

```
cout << numbers_8 << endl;
```

I just wrote (int) before numbers_8 and now it looks fine.